# Transformar UIImage em Array Byte

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Preciso transformar uma imagem em array de bytes, como faço para transformar essa imagem em um Array Bytes?

Comment: Pergunta: você quer um array de bytes que represente um arquivo JPEG ou PNG, como a resposta do @carlosfigueira ilustrou, ou quer um array de bytes com o framebuffer da imagem em si? Se a resposta dele está correta, seria legal mencionar isto na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation) ou [UIImagePNGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) pra coverter a sua imagem em um `NSData`. A partir daí pode alocar um array de bytes do tamanho do dado, e copiar os bytes para ele, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
UIImage *image = [UImage imageNamed:@"foto.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *bytes = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(bytes, [data bytes], len);
```